# PHP loop within a loop

Tags: php, loops

```
<? foreach($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>

<div id="<? echo $i; ?>" class="item" data-delay=<? echo $j; ?>>

<? } ?>
```

I need $j = j + 0.5 for the first 3 of the data-delay attr value. Means the output should be like this

```
<div id="0" class="item" data-delay="0"></div>
<div id="1" class="item" data-delay="0.5"></div>
<div id="2" class="item" data-delay="1"></div>
<div id="4" class="item" ></div>
<div id="5" class="item" ></div>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: and change `foreach` to `for`, foreach is used to iterate an array

Answer (score 1):

This code will do what you need

```
<? for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>
    if($i < 3)
        <div id="<? echo $i; ?>" class="item" data-delay=<? echo round($i/2,1); ?>>
    else
        <div id="<? echo $i; ?>" class="item">
<? } ?>
```

Comment: <?php echo $j += 0.5 . 's'; }?> is something wrong here? I cant concenate 's' at the end

Comment: @jameslebron change it to this <?php echo $j += 0.5 , 's'; }?>

Comment: @jameslebron you can't concatenate operation ($j += 0.5) with string ('s'). If you replace dot with coma it's looks like multiple parameters to echo function, but no concatenate.